# Checking if column exists in BIMC table, SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I have a HANA SQL query I execute to determine which cubes/views belong to a particular HANA catalog. I want to make sure I'm including HDI-based views in the results set, and to that end I want to use the QUALIFIED_NAME column in the BIMC_ALL_AUTHORIZED_CUBES/BIMC_CUBES etc system tables. However, I want to make sure I'm supporting pre-HDI version of HANA, so it's possible I'll encounter a case where the QUALIFIED_NAME column doesn't exist in one of those tables.

How can I check whether the QUALIFIED_NAME column exists in HANA SQL Script? Preferably without checking the HANA version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to query HANA system views that contain all columns for each table:

```
SELECT
 SCHEMA_NAME,
 TABLE_NAME,
 COLUMN_NAME,
 DATA_TYPE_NAME,
 LENGTH,
 SCALE,
 IS_NULLABLE,
 DEFAULT_VALUE,
 COLLATION,
 POSITION
FROM SYS.TABLE_COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = "QUALIFIED_NAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

`QUALIFIED_NAME` was introduced in HANA 1 SPS 11. You can check the version of HANA in use using the following query:

`Select VERSION from "SYS"."M_DATABASE"`

You can interpret the version number returned using the following examples:

```
        01.00.0091 00-1418659308 => HANA 1.0 SPS09
        1.00.091.00.1418659308 => HANA 1.0 SPS09
        1.00.122.09.1493036600 => HANA 1.0 SPS12
```